# In Area51, it says I have used all five off-topic votes when I have only used four

Tags: bug, status-deferred, area-51, voting

I am following the Game Development proposal, and I have only used four of my five off-topic votes, but when I try to use my last one, it says I have already used all my votes. Why?

Comment: Same thing happening to me on the Popular Natural Science proposal.

Comment: Same for me: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54968/i-cant-find-my-fith-off-topic-vote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Your fifth off-topic vote is on a question which has been deleted.
>   We'll add an answer to this question when we decide how to best handle this scenario.
>   – emmett♦

(comment to my [duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54968/i-cant-find-my-fifth-off-topic-vote-closed))

Answer (score 1):

Now it just shows "You have 0 off-topic votes left on this proposal" on the 5th one