# I can't find my fifth off-topic vote

Tags: support, bug, area-51, voting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In Area51, it says I have used all five off-topic votes when I have only used four.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53498/in-area51-it-says-i-have-used-all-five-off-topic-votes-when-i-have-only-used-fou)

At [Physics](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1908/physics?referrer=Ho2q28uHijgN5QfMOt5KEg2) I checked the 'my votes' tab three times and off-topic twice. I only count 4 off-topic votes, but when I try to vote another question as off-topic, I receive the out of votes message. My user ID at Area 51 is 133.

**Edit**
I *cannot* cast my fifth vote. When I uncast another vote, *then* I get the "0 votes remaining" message. It is really miscounted.

Comment: Related, possible duplicate if status-completed will be removed: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53498/in-area-51-it-says-i-have-used-all-five-off-topic-votes-when-i-have-only-used-fo

Comment: Your fifth off-topic vote is on a question which has been deleted. We'll add an answer to this question when we decide how to best handle this scenario.

Comment: @emmett Thanks. In this case is doesn't matter any more since the Physics proposal has moved into commitment phase, but I'd appreciate if the deletion of a question also freed the cast votes again - at least after a 24 hour grace period since the question might be undeleted again. But then I'd feature-request a notification of freed votes of course... Sorry for bothering :-7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See:

[In Area51, it says I have used all five off-topic votes when I have only used four](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53498/in-area-51-it-says-i-have-used-all-five-off-topic-votes-when-i-have-only-used-fo)

Comment: Sorry, no. I *cannot* cast my fith vote. When I uncast another vote, *then* I get the "0 votes remaining" message. It is really miscounted.

Comment: oh, I see, your bug report is actually *not* completed but also misunderstood. So I'll flag this as a duplicate, thanks for the link