# Deleted sample questions still count on area 51?

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51

In the Japanese proposal, I currently have upvotes on 4 questions visible.  However, I can't vote for another one, as it claims I have 5 upvotes.  I'm wondering if a question got "deleted", and it's still counting my vote for that deleted question.  I'd like to be able to recind that vote and put it toward something else.

Comment: possible duplicate of [I can't find my fifth off-topic vote](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54968/i-cant-find-my-fifth-off-topic-vote)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Your fifth off-topic vote is on a question which has been deleted. We'll add an answer to this question when we decide how to best handle this scenario. – Emmett♦

(comment on [my dupe](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54968/i-cant-find-my-fifth-off-topic-vote))

It is quite likely that bug, and I second it should be fixed. It is unlikely that a deleted question will be undeleted after several days, so the vote should be given back.

Answer (score 0):

Votes on deleted questions no longer count toward the 5-vote limit.