# Regular users can remove restricted tags with rollback

Tags: bug, tags, rollbacks, moderator-tags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why am I allowed to delete moderator-only tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6368/why-am-i-allowed-to-delete-moderator-only-tags)

Check out the [revision history](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/53498/revisions) for [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53498/in-area51-it-says-i-have-used-all-five-off-topic-votes-when-i-have-only-used-fou).  Revision #3 consisted of the addition of the restricted, moderator-only red tag — hurrah for search keywords — `[status-completed]`.  In revision #4, the OP rolled back to the original version of the question, which stripped off the restricted tag.

I am not clear on whether this is possible for any rollback-enabled user or only the OP.  But either way, this seems like a loophole in the moderator-only nature of restricted tags; non-mods shouldn't be able to remove restricted tags.

Comment: Any user that can rollback [seems to be able to do this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/46483/revisions).

Comment: [You can also add removed moderator tags by using rollback](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6368/why-am-i-allowed-to-delete-moderator-only-tags).

Comment: Aw, not sure how I missed that dupe.  Thanks @sth.